# Convert json string to datatable using C#.NET?

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0, datatable

when I Pass Integer values then JsonData Convert to Datatable ..
When I Pass Decimal values I am getting error ..
Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <1.5> in VAT Column.

```
 var dt1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonData);
```

Here is My JSON Data 
[{"Stateid":1,"VAT":0,"CST":0},
{"Stateid":2,"VAT":"1.5","CST":"1.5"},
{"Stateid":3,"VAT":0,"CST":0},{"Stateid":4,"VAT":0,"CST":0},{"Stateid":5,"VAT":0,"CST":0},{"Stateid":6,"VAT":0,"CST":0},{"Stateid":7,"VAT":0,"CST":0},{"Stateid":8,"VAT":0,"CST":0},{"Stateid":9,"VAT":0,"CST":0},{"Stateid":10,"VAT":0,"CST":0},

Comment: what is this datatable ?

Comment: I Need to Get Data into DataTable

Comment: can i see how you created your datatable columns ?

Comment: Stateid,VAT,CST..I am using Angular JS..Here the values from Scope

Comment: that is ok, what is the datatype for VAT column ?

Comment: I am using Var datatype

Comment: try with putting it as decimal type

Comment: I think In angular js we are using Var DataType Only

Comment: what i mean in the .NET code which datatype are you using?

Comment: For Getting VAT and CST Datatype is DECIMAL

Comment: public List<Products> UpdateProducts(string jsonData)
        {
            var dt1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonData);
            
            return store.UpdateProducts(dt1);
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string jsonData = "[{\"Stateid\":1,\"VAT\":\"0\",\"CST\":\"0\"}, {\"Stateid\":2,\"VAT\":\"1.5\",\"CST\":\"1.5\"}, {\"Stateid\":3,\"VAT\":\"0\",\"CST\":\"0\"},{\"Stateid\":4,\"VAT\":\"0\",\"CST\":\"0\"},{\"Stateid\":5,\"VAT\":\"0\",\"CST\":\"0\"},{\"Stateid\":6,\"VAT\":\"0\",\"CST\":\"0\"},{\"Stateid\":7,\"VAT\":\"0\",\"CST\":\"0\"},{\"Stateid\":8,\"VAT\":\"0\",\"CST\":\"0\"},{\"Stateid\":9,\"VAT\":\"0\",\"CST\":\"0\"}]" ;
        var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonData);
    }
```

What i found your VAT is marked as int in first record but then it marked as 1.5 in string so it give you error

so i convert all data in string and try it done.